# How to create multiple vue instances in the vue-cli webpack template

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning vue.js, and currently trying out different things. I suppose I am raising multiple questions actually:

Assuming my application have two pages "/foo" and "/bar". And my router looks something like:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/foo'
    },
    {
      path: '/foo',
      name: 'fc',
      component: FooComponent
    },
    {
      path: '/bar',
      name: 'bc',
      component: BarComponent
    }

  ]
})
```

I want to import different css frameworks between these pages.

for example: "/foo" uses Bulma, and "/bar" uses Bootstrap. Or "/foo" uses Bulma, but "/bar" without any style at all.

I tried only importing "bulma.css" in the `<script>` section of my "foo" component:

```
<script>
import baz from '@/components/baz'
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'

export default {
  ...
}
</script>
```

But the style still leaks to the Bar component.

Should I create multiple vue instances in the case?

And how should I do that if I am using the webpack template from vue-cli?

And how to router between these two instances?

Thanks a lot!